# create a macro variable based on a condition SAS

Tags: select, sas, having, insert-into, proc-sql

I have the following table

```
data have;
    input x1;
    datalines;
    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
    6
    7
    8
    9
    10
    11
    ;
run;
```

and I'm trying to create a macro variable which allocates the number of distinct entries up to a maximum of ten so I can automatically create the right number of bins for a histogram later (max 10 bins)

the code i'm currently trying to leverage is as follows but I'm unsure how to allocate the macro variable when there are more than 10 distinct observations

```
PROC SQL NOPRINT;
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT X1)
        INTO: BIN_X1
        FROM HAVE
        HAVING (COUNT(DISTINCT X1) LE 10);
QUIT;
```

How do I allocate the macro variable to be 10 if there are more than 10 distinct obs?

Comment: It sounds like you may want to use PROC RANK here with GROUPS=10?

Comment: I will read up about PROC RANK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the SAS function `min(,)` to truncate the count to a maximum of 10.

```
proc sql noprint;
  select min(count(distinct x1),10)
    into :bin_x1 trimmed
  from have
  ;
quit;
```

So the SQL aggregate function `count()` will see how many distinct values of X1 exist in the dataset and then the SAS function `min(,)` will select the min of that number and 10.

Note that the SAS functions (min,max,etc) take two or more arguments and work just on those arguments for the current observation, but the SQL aggregate functions (min,max,etc) take only one argument and aggregate the values that argument represents across multiple observations.

Comment: nice, p.s. does the trimmed statement have any impact?

Comment: The `timmed` keyword will remove the spaces caused by converting a number to text so that it can be stored in a macro variable.

Comment: I've been looking for this my whole life

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to put 10 in a macro list, then you can use outobs= to limit the records. Question is which 10 records do you want when there are more than 10?

```
PROC SQL outobs=10;
SELECT X1
    INTO: BIN_X1 separated by ","
    FROM HAVE;
    QUIT;

    %put &Bin_x1;
```

Comment: I'm looking to count the total number of distinct observations, if there are more than ten distinct obs i.e. above there is a range of 11 distinct entries then i'd force the variable to be 10

Comment: So implementing automatic binning? Use NLEVELS within PROC FREQ to get the number of distinct values and then use macro logic to determine if you need to bin and then how you want to bin. there are some written macros around if you're not interested in rolling your own: http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings17/0969-2017.pdf